# sudoers allow command with one option - refuse with other option

Tags: linux, sudo, sudoers

I am looking for a solution to the following:

Allow in sudoers file the execution on a command with option A, but refuse the same command with option B:

Example:
Allow this:
sudo my_command optionA

Dissallow this:
sudo my_command optionB

Is this possible ?

Comment: I have answered your question, but please bear in mind, that it belongs more to serverfault.com or superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

You can easily specify which parameters are allowed.

For example, I have a user `testuser`. The file you must edit is `/etc/sudoers`, but remember to do it with `visudo` command - it verifies the content of the file, so you won't end up with a typo that would prevent you from sudo'ing again (sometimes it's the only way to access root account).

So, enter `visudo`.

Let's say, that I want to allow test to run `/bin/yes --help`. I don't have right to `x` it for any other user than root.

What you want to add is:

```
testuser ALL=(ALL) /bin/yes --help
```

It means that `testuser` can run `/bin/yes --help` from any host as any user. By default, `sudo /bin/yes --help` will ask for `testuser`'s password. `sudo /bin/yes` will give `access denied`.

If you want to allow it without providing a password, replace the line with:

```
testuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/yes --help
```

Please note that you cannot **explicitly** deny a parameter. If the `testuser` is a member of default sudoers group, this method will not work.

Comment: thanks...seems to work. I shall test to see for caveats in the commands options. thanks again

Comment: Sure thing! And if it works for you just fine, please accept my answer :) And if not - edit your question and add a comment here, so I'd get notified.